# Container startup failed with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when trying to run a bare minimum test to see that spring boot starts up properly:

```
ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
```

This is what I have

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = {"management.server.port="}, // To be able to use mockMvc to access the actuators.
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {Application.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)
@ComponentScan
@Log4j2
public abstract class SpringBootComponentTest {

  protected static final WireMockServer WIRE_MOCK_SERVER = new WireMockServer(0);

  private enum DatabaseType {
    LOCAL_POSTGRES,
    DOCKER_POSTGRES
  }

  @BeforeAll
  static void startWireMock() {
    WIRE_MOCK_SERVER.start();
  }

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void applicationProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    DatabaseType databaseType = getDatabaseType();

    log.info("Overriding application context with database type {}", databaseType);
    switch (databaseType) {
      case DOCKER_POSTGRES:
        PostgresContainer postgreSQLContainer = PostgresContainer.getInstance();
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
        break;
      case LOCAL_POSTGRES:
        //...
        break;
    }
  }

  private static DatabaseType getDatabaseType() {
    try {
      return DatabaseType.valueOf(System.getenv("TEST_DB"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return DatabaseType.DOCKER_POSTGRES;
    }
  }

@Test
  void checkThatSpringBootLoadsProperlyWithoutAnythingElse() {}
}
```

and

```
public class PostgresContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<PostgresContainer> {

  private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:14.4";

  @Container private static PostgresContainer container;

  private PostgresContainer() {
    super(IMAGE_VERSION);
  }

  public static PostgresContainer getInstance() {
    if (container == null) {
      container =
          new PostgresContainer()
              .withDatabaseName("testDb")
              .withUsername("testUser")
              .withPassword("testPasswordTestPassword");
      container.start();
    }
    return container;
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {
    super.start(); // error points to this line
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    // do nothing, JVM handles shut down
  }
}
```

The full stacktrace is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1a2e563e testClass = com.gloot.foobar.ApplicationTest, locations = [], classes = [com.gloot.foobar.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["management.server.port=", "org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@5b066c33 key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5efa40fe, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2d29b4ee, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4470fbd6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6bb4dd34, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@afb938fd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ee5424e7], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:349)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.maybeStart(RyukResourceReaper.java:78)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.init(RyukResourceReaper.java:42)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:209)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:89)
    at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:108)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:321)
    at com.gloot.foobar.PostgresContainer.start(PostgresContainer.java:30)
    at com.gloot.foobar.PostgresContainer.getInstance(PostgresContainer.java:23)
    at com.gloot.foobar.SpringBootComponentTest.applicationProperties(SpringBootComponentTest.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.lambda$buildDynamicPropertiesMap$3(DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.java:84)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.buildDynamicPropertiesMap(DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.customizeContext(DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:433)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:603)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:542)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown"}

    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.post(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:102)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:31)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:21)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:43)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:441)
    ... 105 more
```

I only get this error on my local machine, my OS is Ubuntu 22.10, Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.0.1

Comment: For starters ditch the `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration`, although not related it doesn't add anything but clutter. THe error states `"message":"cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown"` so you might have an incompatible container, I also don't really get why you are wrapping it.

Comment: @M.Deinum have those annotations since I will have other test classes that will extend this one and will require those. Would the incompatible container explain why it doesnt work on my machine but it works for my coworker?

Comment: Ehrm... If you require those your test is already flawed (as you would be mixing JUnit4 and Junit5 but rely on the latter to do the bootstrapping, I suspect that isn't really what you want).

Answer (score 0):

This issue all started when I upgraded my OS version to Ubuntu 22.10 and it was related to the version of docker I had installed. Removing the old version and installing the latest version go it working for me, by following this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu